Is there a function to identify the top 10 values across multiple metrics of a table that is already ranking the top 10 of one metric?
I am creating a very simple data table for a survey I completed with the following code:
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

f2 <- df1 %>%
  arrange(desc(Eigen.Vector.Centrality)) %>%
  slice(1:10) %>%
  select(ID, Eigen.Vector.Centrality, Modularity.Class, Betweenness.Centrality, Bridging.Centrality, Bridging.Coefficient, Degree, Clustering.Coefficient, Eccentricity)  # Replace these with the column names you want to display
print(df2)

datatable(df2)


I'm wondering if there is any way to add a function to this table that will highlight (in red) the values for each metric (column) that the ID (row) is also in the top 10 of that field? So for example, I am primarily looking at the top 10 eigen vector values (EVC) from my data and graphing the rest of the relationship metrics like modularity, degree, etc. associated with those values in my table, but if whatever survey ID was ranked number 1 for EVC was also in the top 10 for "Modularity.Class" how can I code the script to identify that it is in the top 10 for any other metrics and highlight the numerical values in the table red without changing the order of the top 10 values on my EVC table or adding other fields to my table?
I haven't tried much else other than manually comparing the individual rankings across each field to the table I created that has all of the metrics on it.
